# depending on client side code in expressjs packages

Tags: node.js, express

I have some packages that create express.js endpoints.  Some of these packages have corresponding client code which uses these APIs.  For a server, it seems to make sense to depend on this client code because the server will be serving up this code in order for the client to interact with the endpoints it exposes.

However, my express code is serving up these files from a single common directory.  npm, however, installs each package in a different directory.  Even in newer versions of node it is possible that this directory structure won't even be flat.  It seems like writing the express related code to locate all the different files to be served up would be excessively complex.

I was reading [npm and front-end packaging](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/101775448305/npm-and-front-end-packaging) and it sounds like npm *wants* to be able to handle this case.  At the time this article was written there were some issues identified - the first problem identified is "node_modules isn’t arranged the way front-end packages need it to be" which is exactly the problem I am having.  The article does not seem to present any solutions, but as it was written almost three years ago there may have been progress made on this front since then.

What is the way to do this now?  Currently as a work-around I have my own installer, but this means that npm doesn't know anything about my client side code and I have to manually install the correct packages.

Update:
Here is a simplified example showing packages and files to serve:

```
server-168: defines services used by this particular server
\- server-168.js

server-core: defines plug-in architecture used by other services and provides default file serving endpoint
\- server-core.js

database-service: exposes database endpoint
\- database-service.js

database-frontend: contains UI for manipulating database in browser
\- database.js

image-service: exposes image manipulation endpoint
\- image-service.js

image-frontend: contains UI for manipulating images
\+- image.js
 |
 \- image.css
```

After installation, the files directory in this case must look like this:

```
files/
    image.js
    image.css
    database.js
```

Currently I am using `npm install git+ssh://.../server-168.git` to install the server, and then a custom installer to install the stuff that goes in the files directory.

Comment: Can you give us specific examples that shows packages, files to serve and current directory structure.  I'm not following how lot of files you need to serve to the client end up in a bunch of different packages?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have updated to show one example.  everything is modular with different servers utilizing some subset of the available packages.  A package may have only a single client-side file or a single javascript file along with some css files.

Comment: You should probably build a deployment script that copies all the resources you want to serve to the client to one or a few directories so you can more easily and securely serve the static resources from a safe location that only contains publicly available files to be served to the client.  You should be deliberate about what can be served anyway (to avoid serving anything you don't intend to) so having to make a list of everything you intend to be public should not be a problem.  Then, your public URL structure is independent of how modules are organized (which is a good thing).

Comment: You could also have each module list for itself, what files are intended to be publicly served (either in a custom section in package.json or in a different json file) and then the script could just go collect all the files that each package wishes to make public and put them where they should be for deployment. It seems like this should be an already supported thing, but I'm not aware of a specific scheme for doing this.  It's very common to have a deployment script that maps between source control system and deployment locations.